# jQuery returns "Unexpected itentifier" while setting src attribute of a script element

Tags: jquery, src, script-tag

I have this little jquery script:

```
$('<script/>')
     .attr('src','some_script.js')
     .appendTo("body");
```

which returns in the console:

```
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:9999/some_script.js?_=1379984053633
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier jquery-latest.min.js:4
(anonymous function) [...]
```

Why have I such a result?  If I change `src` with, say, `class`, I obtain no error.

I am running a webserver through node.js on port 9999.

Comment: are there any syntax error in the `some_script.js` file

Comment: it contains `$("body").css("color","blue");`, The script tag is actually inserted and the js loaded.

Comment: what is the content of http://localhost:9999/some_position ?

Comment: Sorry, I changed some_position with some_script.js. I corrected in the listing.